# Issue with DateJoined & CreatedDate

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have 'CreatedDate' in 'ListSubscribers' Data view and 'DateJoined' in 'Subscribers' Data View. According to Documentation, both must have same value since both are the date when Subscriber was added to a List. But when I did an extract, we have multiple records with different value in 'DateJoined' column and identical value in 'CreatedDate' which we are not understanding. Please explain if anyone has any idea as we are really stuck.
            [OR]
Is there a way to optimize below query so we will get just one row with most recent date of 'DateJoined' field? Your help is much appreciated.

```
select l.ListID, l.ListName, l.EmailAddress,Sub.DateJoined, l.AddMethod,l.Addedby, l.CreatedDate, a.first_name_o, a.last_name_o, a.company_o, a.state_o, a.country_o, l.DateUnsubscribed, l.Status,a.job_title_o, a.library_type_o, a.functional_area_o, a.language_o, S.EventDate

from ent._EnterpriseAttribute a
LEFT join _ListSubscribers l on a._SubscriberID = l.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _Sent S on  a._SubscriberID = S.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN ent._Subscribers Sub on a._SubscriberID = Sub.SubscriberID

where L.ListName <> 'All Subscribers' and Sub.DateJoined between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-01' and (l.AddMethod='WebApplication' OR l.AddMethod='API') and S.EventDate<>''
```

Comment: Is the list a publication list or the AllSubscribers? Is the Date Joined (from `_Subscribers` before the CreatedDate (from `_ListSubscribers`)?

Comment: It's All Subscribers List. And CreatedDate comes first and then DateJoined. We have 10 entries with CreatedDate=4thjan and DateJoined with different dates after 4th Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why both fields store different data but I could refine my query to get unique rows with most recent value in 'DateJoined' and with Last Email Sent Date.

```
select l.ListID, l.ListName, l.EmailAddress, MAX(Sub.DateJoined) AS  'DateJoined', l.AddMethod,l.Addedby, l.CreatedDate, a.first_name_o, a.last_name_o, a.company_o, a.state_o, a.country_o, l.DateUnsubscribed, l.Status,a.job_title_o, a.library_type_o, a.functional_area_o, a.language_o, MAX(S.EventDate) AS 'EventDate'

from ent._EnterpriseAttribute a
LEFT join _ListSubscribers l on a._SubscriberID = l.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _Sent S on  a._SubscriberID = S.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN ent._Subscribers Sub on a._SubscriberID = Sub.SubscriberID

where L.ListName <> 'All Subscribers' and Sub.DateJoined between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-01' and (l.AddMethod='WebApplication' OR l.AddMethod='API') and S.EventDate=''

Group by l.ListID, l.ListName, l.EmailAddress, l.AddMethod,l.Addedby, l.CreatedDate, a.first_name_o, a.last_name_o, a.company_o, a.state_o, a.country_o, l.DateUnsubscribed, l.Status,a.job_title_o, a.library_type_o, a.functional_area_o, a.language_o
```